# C# Client Testlink

Tags: c#, client, testlink

Is there a C# Client to use and integrate with the Testlink?

I just saw Java Client using the Eclipse, but I want to use Testlink integrate with my Visual Studio IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Gallio adapter:

Path. http://code.google.com/p/gallio-testlink-adapter/

Additional info with integration also with NUnit: 
- https://github.com/smeyn/gallio-testlink-adapter/wiki/NUnit-Run-Through

Comment: The NUnit link you provided contains a great C# example using TestLink. This answered all the questions I had around using it with C#.

Answer (score -1):

Yes with there is one which I used to link my test suite with test link.
Testlink is providing API through which you can add delete and update your testcases.
Go to tools and then search testlink just add it and consume

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ifkaa.jpg]